# How to center my webpage

Tags: web, center

http://pastebin.com/GQ6Q0dti

-- I want to center my webpage but I've found no successful tutorials.
Could someone please help me and fix my problem
I just want to center my page. Thanks

Comment: Please add code to your question. Code snippets outside of SO tend to get deleted, making your question and the answers useless to others.

Comment: add your html code please

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center it horizontally+vertically use `position: absolute;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DRsJK/)

```
.center {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   height: 200px;
   width: 400px;
   margin-top: -100px; /* Half of container height */
   margin-left: -200px; /* Half of container width */
}
```

and if you want to center it only horizontally simply use this

```
margin: 0 auto;
        ^    ^
       T/B  L/R
```

Just don't forget the width to the container ;)

Comment: Now my web page is more to the left and there is a huge gap on the right area

Answer (score 0):

if  you want to make horizontal center only, the best way is not to use `absolute` position, use default position and set `margin:0px auto;`

```
#Table_01 {
    width:792px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#template {
   height:1584px;
}
```